# Modifying / Adding extra stuff to PDO bindParam()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, php-5.4

does anyone know by any chance if there is a clean way (or any way at all) to change PDO's bindParam?

We're implementing extra security measures for our websites (filters for inputs) and so far it seems that the best way to add it to every single website we have efficiently (every website we have is different but the thing they have in common is they all use PDO) would be to somehow make PDO bindParam call our function on it's parameters, so that every single input in the bindParam would be filtered appropriately.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a feeling you are doing filtering wrong. What in specific is it that you are doing?

Comment: Let me start by saying that this is an absolutely horrible idea and you should NOT do this however [runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) can be used to overwrite core PHP functions. Again, horrible idea. With that said the obvious choice here is to refactor the way you're doing filtering.

Comment: No need for runkit. Just extend `PDOStatement`. But yeah OP is doing something wrong.

Comment: BTW yes that still needs code changes :)

Comment: Possible [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: We handle lots of HTML input and currently adding HTML filtering with [kses](https://github.com/RichardVasquez/kses) to only allow a whitelist of tags and attributes. In the newer websites that use OOP I simply incorporated that into one general DB-helper-class that handles PDO and which is being extended by other classes. But plenty of other old websites use separate functions for every MySQL query (that's probably like 200+ functions). So I was just looking into possibilities of not updating thousands and thousands of functions that use PDO and just updating PDO itself. :)

Comment: P.S. Those old websites that don't use OOP and have separate function for every simple thing were not written by me but now they are my responsibility. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by extending PDO classes:

```
class CustomDBConnection {

    private static $conn;

    // either create a new connection or return an existing one
    public static function getInstance() {
        if (self::$conn == null) {
            global $db_hostname, $db_database, $db_username, $db_password; // probably better to store these within this class but this was quicker
            self::$conn = new CustomPDO("mysql:host=$db_hostname;dbname=$db_database;charset=utf8", $db_username, $db_password, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
        }

        return self::$conn;
    }
}

class CustomPDO extends PDO {

    public function __construct($dsn, $username = null, $password = null, $driver_options = array()) {

        parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password, $driver_options);

        // Attach customised PDOStatement class
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array('CustomPDOStatement', array($this)));
    }
}

class CustomPDOStatement extends PDOStatement {

    private $conn;

    protected function __construct($conn) {
        $this->conn = $conn; // this is most likely useless at this moment
    }

    public function bindParam($parameter, &$variable, $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR, $length = null, $driver_options = null) {
        $variable = InputProtection::detachEvilHTML($variable);

        parent::bindParam($parameter, $variable, $data_type, $length, $driver_options);
    }

    public function bindValue($parameter, $value, $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR) {
        $value = InputProtection::detachEvilHTML($value);

        parent::bindValue($parameter, $value, $data_type);
    }
}
```

So I basically do `$db = CustomDBConnection::getInstance();` now instead of `$db = new PDO(.......);`